# Android SQLite: Joins and cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, join, database-cursor

I have the following tables in an sqlite database:

```
items
______
 _id (PK)
name
section_subsection_id (FK)

section_subsections
______
_id (PK)
section_id (FK)
subsection_id (FK)

subsections
______
_id (PK)
name

sections
______
_id (PK)
name
```

I would like to provide a certain keyword to *subsections* that would only grab only those that match this keyword under a limit, say x, and count all the *items* under this *section* AND *subsection* match.

I have used several queries, here is one:

```
String selectQuery = "Select subsections.name, subsections._id, temp.count as count 
FROM subsections LEFT JOIN 
sections_subsections ON subsections._id = sections_subsections.subsection_id 
JOIN items (SELECT count(items._id) as count from items) temp 
ON items.section_subsection_id = sections_subsections._id 
WHERE subsections.name LIKE 'keyword' AND sections_subsections.section_id = 1 ORDER BY
subsections.name ASC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0 ";
```

When I try to iterate through the results, I get the list matching the keyword search but the *count* always displays the last count value from the result set. When I run the raw query in sqlite shell, I see the correct counts in the column with the respective rows, but iterating through the cursor in Android/Java seems to have a problem. Or possibly my query?

So for ListView in the app I would get same counts (that is all 20s), but in shell I see *count* with correct value. In fact, during cursor iteration, if I Log.d *count* to the screen it is also all 20s, yet the other column value *name* is different. What is wrong with my query? Or how do I correctly iterate through a table with multiple joins?

```
_id  name    count 
 ---------------   
1    item1   79
2    item2   30
3    item3   20
```

EDIT:
I'm doing something like this in Java:

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if (cursor != null) {
cursor.moveToFirst();
}

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
do {
SubSection subSection = new SubSection();                      
subSection.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));                     subSection.setSubSectionName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TABLE_SUBSECTIONS_SUBSECTION_NAME)));
subSection.setRecords(cursor.getColumnIndex("count"));
subSections.add(subSection);
}
while 
(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below query

```
Select subsections.name, subsections._id, (SELECT count(items._id) from items WHERE items.section_subsection_id = sections_subsections._id) as count 
FROM subsections LEFT JOIN 
sections_subsections ON subsections._id = sections_subsections.subsection_id 
WHERE subsections.name LIKE 'keyword' AND sections.name = 'Category' ORDER BY
subsections.name ASC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0 ";
```

Comment: Thanks! Where should the second closing bracket be?

Comment: just after the end of sub query, did you run the code?

Comment: Okay, I have tried it. Returns the same thing. The value of the last count result; To verify, I have used Log during cursor iteration: `Log.d(LOG, cursor.getColumnIndex("count") + "");` I ran this sql command in sqlite shell and can see the correct count, just as is the case with my previous queries.

Comment: if the above Log.d(LOG, cursor.getColumnIndex("count") + "") prints what you expect then check your model may be something is wrong with subSection.setRecords(...), try print Log.d(LOG, String.valueOf
(subSection.getRecords())) to see if the value is assigned properly oor post where are you using submenu at the frontend

Comment: No it does not print what I expect. It prints the count value of the last record 50 times as we have a limit/result set of 50. I can see what I expect via terminal shell.

Comment: `sections.name = 'Category'` should actually be: `sections_subsections.section_id = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Syed Waqas, your answer is correct for joining. The problem was not my queries actually. It was my cursor call. I should have used: `cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("count"))` instead of what I have in my original question. I don't know how I managed to not notice this big mistake. For everyone else, you can debug your cursor with the lovely DatabseUtils. :)

```
Log.d(LOG, "ROW: " + DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
```